# How to show my public repositories of github, on my Website

Tags: php, html, laravel, api, github

I want to show all the public repositories of my Github account on my website. The website is created fully on laravel. Users can view my public repositories from my website without going to my github profile.

Comment: It should help you : https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

Comment: [Laravel Github](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub) might be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this awesome library from Packagist

```
composer install knplabs/github-api
```

https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/github-api

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new \Github\Client();
$repositories = $client->api('user')->repositories('delboy1978uk');
```